# Display taxonomy terms when adding a link in the admin

Tags: taxonomy, search, admin

When you add a link in the admin and make a research, all post types are displayed, but I wondered if there is an easy way to display also taxonomy terms. It would be very useful.

Thanks!

[image: adding link in the admin]

Comment: this is specific to the classic editor right? I'm assuming that's the old editors link insert dialog? _The version in the block editor already lists terms_. I edited out the part where you asked if there was a plugin that did this as it would have forced me to close your question as offtopic, you can't ask for recommendations ehre

Comment: Yes this box appears in the classic editor, and also with Advanced Custom Field when using the "link" field type.